# Drag Drop and Verify in Visual Basic (VS 2012 V11)

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, directory

I have a program with two text boxes. One is for a file path the other for a folder path (directory). Right now, my drag and drop feature properly allows only files paths in one text box and folder paths (directories) in the other.

However, I'm not certain if my verification method is proper.
Here are the two parts of the code that verify if file or directory:

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

            Dim filePathDragDrop() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

            For Each pathTemp In filePathDragDrop

                ' This checks if it is a file
                If File.GetAttributes(pathTemp) = FileAttributes.Archive Then
                    TextBoxCopyFrom.Text = pathTemp
                End If

            Next

        End If
```

And for checking for directory a similar set up as above only this is different

```
' Checks for directory
 If File.GetAttributes(pathTemp) = FileAttributes.Directory Then
                    TextBoxCopyTo.Text = pathTemp
                End If
```

**Is this the proper way to check if the file being dropped is indeed a file, 
and if the folder (directory) being dropped is indeed a folder (directory)?**

Is there any item that could be dropped that would be incorrectly verified?

I am assuming the archive part of "FileAttributes.Archive" pertains to file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not correct.  The Archive attribute doesn't have to be turned on.  It will be turned off when the user has used a backup program and the file hasn't changed since it was backed-up.  Not actually sure if backup programs still work that way these days, but you can't make any assumptions.

The test for a directory is not correct.  You'll need to test it like this:

```
If (File.GetAttributes(pathTemp) And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory Then
   '' It's a directory
Else
   '' It's a file
End If
```

Comment: Okay, that worked! But, is there a test for file something like: "If (File.GetAttributes(pathTemp) And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.File Then ' it's a file"  I know that there is no ".file" but is there something to test for file (aside from the inverse test of, "is not directory then file").

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I might be assuming that this: "If (File.GetAttributes(pathTemp) And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory"  is checking to see if the item being dragged and dropped is a directory. If "FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory is true" then yes the item being dragged and dropped is a directory. The  "else" statement is saying that, if the item being dragged dropped is NOT a directory then it must be a file (for instance: .txt, .exe, .oggs, .png, .jpg, etc.). What I'm asking is that is there a way to see if what is dragged dropped is .txt, .ogg, .png, etc.?